# C++ unsigned char allocating issue

Tags: c++, memory, char, unsigned

I am having a problem using the code below:

```
unsigned char ciphertext[(int)(strlen ((char *)plaintext) * 1.5)];
```

When the code hits this line on executing, it fails when the size is `3687192`.

However, it succeeds for the following values:

```
18
54
60
90
173196
224100
```

So, how can I overcome this problem?

Sidenote, the declaration MUST stay in the format `unsigned char VARNAME` since I have to use it within the OPENSSL encryption / decryption routine which requires a `unsigned char` variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're running into the limit on the size of a stack frame. Allocate it dynamically using `new char[size];` or use `std::string`.

Comment: VLA's aren't standard c++.

Comment: @Barmar `std::vector<unsigned char>` works even better in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Literally and figuratively!

Comment: @KeithThompson - but, but, but, the compiler told me to do it! <g>

Comment: @KeithThompson non-constant array sizes are allowed by some compilers as an extension (e.g. `gcc`) since they also double as C compilers, and that's a C feature. I'm not surprised to see people confused by this. The `(int)` cast is necessary because of the `* 1.5` in the expression.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I'm not sure the support for VLAs (variable-length arrays) as an extension by g++ is directly related to their support in C; the compiler front ends are distinct. It was probably just reasonably easy to implement. You're right about the need for the cast (though `(size_t)` would make a bit more sense, or `... * 3 / 2`). Deleting my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is all in the comments, but I'm going to make it explicit.

Local variables are generally allocated on the stack. The stack has limits, it's not allowed to grow infinitely large. Once you've reached the limit, you have no choice but to allocate the variable on the heap instead.

You have many choices for how to do this, but I'm going to recommend two. The first is `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> ciphertext(strlen ((char *)plaintext) * 3 / 2, 0);
```

To pass this array to another function, use `&ciphertext[0]`.

The second is `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<unsigned char> ciphertext = new unsigned char[strlen ((char *)plaintext) * 3 / 2];
```